# Power bi Api Reresh with service principale or?

Tags: api, powerbi

I am trying to build a step into my data pipeline that could refresh the power bi report.

I have made it to this far that my AAD Client ID triggers the refresh, but it always asks my personal password, plus the mfa.

Is there a way to use a service principal or something that wouldn't require a personal password?

I have used the following link for testing:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/manageRefresh.ps1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service principal account to authenticate, it is in preview at the moment.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/use-power-bi-api-with-service-principal-preview/